# reading two vectors from file

Tags: c++, file

[Problem is described here.](http://codeeval.com/browse/30/)
I tried to solve it using code that's below, but it's not working.

```
const char* filename = "test.txt";
ifstream file1(filename);
vector<int> v1;
vector<int> v2;
vector<int> res;

int number;
char c;

while(1){
    while(1){
        v1.push_back(number);
        file1.get(c);
        if (c==';') break;
    }

    while(1){
        v2.push_back(number);
        file1.get(c);
        if (c=='\n') break;
    }

    for (vector<int>::iterator it = v2.begin(); it!=v2.end(); it++)
        cout << *it << ',';
    cout << endl;
    file1.get(c);
    if (c==EOF) break;
    file1.unget();
}
```

There is a problem with reading end of line. Is `c=='\n'` right?

Comment: c == '\n' should match an end of line character.  I think your problem lies elsewhere.  Someone will probably point it out, but have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Describe what you are trying to do here (don't link elsewhere) and explain specifically what is not working

Comment: Somewhat unrelated to the problem, but you should use `while (c != ';')` and `while (c != '\n')` rather than `while (1)`. It is considered better practice

Comment: You are repeatedly storing the same uninitialized number.  Why would you think that this works?

Answer (score 2):

To read a line, you should use:

`istream& getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim);`

In your case, with a delimiter of `';'`

Then you can parse numbers in the same way, by using delimiter of `','`

like this:

```
std::string line, temp;
std::getline(file1,line,';'); //get a line. (till ';')
std::istringstream s1 (line); //init stream with the whole line
while(std::getline(s1,temp,',')){//get a number as string from the line. (till ',')
   int n;
   std::istringstream s2(temp);
   s2>>n; //convert string number to numeric value
   //now you can push it into the vector...
}
```